# '$|x|$ to power of $x$' inequality with polynomial exponent

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, absolute-value

I have found this in a old math book and I completly don't know how to deal with it:
$$|x-1|^{x^4-4x^3+3x^2}<1$$
I've looked for similar problems on internet but I couldn't find anything. You can factor the exponent but it isn't any better.
The book says solution is $x\in(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ and WolframAlpha agrees with it.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking logarithms, we find that $$(x^4-4x^3+3x^2)\ln|x-1|<\ln 1 \implies x^2(x-1)(x-3)\ln|x-1|<0$$ We know that the logarithmic term can never equal $0$, so the inequality can be simplified to $$x^2(x-1)(x-3)<0$$ Thus the solution is $$x\in(0,1)\cup(2,3)$$ since when $x \in [1, 2]$, both $\ln|x-1|$ and $x-3$ are less than or equal to $0$ which makes the LHS positive.

Comment: $\log|x-1| = 0$ if $x\in\{0,2\}$.  It is negative if $x \in (0,2)\setminus\{1\}$, undefined if $x=1$, and positive otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @XavierHenderson In the first inequality, if $x \in (0, 1)$ then three terms are negative so the inequality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$k^n<1$ if $0<k<1,n>0$ or $k>1,n<0$.

What values give $|x-1|<1$ or $|x-1|>1$?

Factorize the exponent. What values give positive/negative exponent?

Which regions satisfy both conditions?